# Using arrays and run time check failure #2-s, Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++

I am calculating the occurrence of numbers, the result is accurate and right:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int max = 51;

int main()
{
    int num = 0;
    int array[max] = { 0 };
    cout << "Enter interger number from 0 to 50 and type in -1 to show occurence:";
    while (num!=-1)
    {
        cin >> num;
        array[num] = array[num]+1;
    }
    cout << "all entered number are:" << endl;
    cout << "Number\tFrequency" << endl;
    for (num = 0; num < max; num++)
    {
        if (array[num]>0)
        {
            cout << num <<"\t"<< array[num] << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the Visual Studio always notify me of the following:

> run-time check failure #2-s,

[image]

Comment: "run-time check failure #2-s" doesn't mean anything to most people. Please include an exact error message and show us what you've discovered by debugging it. In addition, show the input that causes the problem so that it's reproducible, or, better yet, hardcode the input into the program.

Comment: You never check if `num` goes out of bounds here: `array[num] `.

Comment: If the user entered any number greater than 50 or less than 0 you are out of bounds. `-1` is out of bounds in  `array[num] = array[num]+1;`

Comment: eh, I think the while loop can prevent this condition because it won't happen? I am still not clear about out of bounds, sorry.......

Comment: ***I think the while loop can prevent this condition because it won't happen?*** No. That is wrong. You `cin >> num;` then execute `array[num] = array[num]+1;` there is no skipping execution of `array[num] = array[num]+1;` because num is less than 0. Also there is no check if num is greater than 50.

Comment: ***I am still not clear about out of bounds*** If the user enters `-1` the program executes `array[-1] = array[-1] + 1;` This is undefined behavior to access out of bounds.

Comment: If I want to use -1 as my endpoint and I still need to use an array, what should I change for preventing this error? seem like I can't use an array because my end point is a negative number.Thanks for helping....

Comment: Place an if statement after the cin to not execute `array[num] = array[num]+1;` if num is less than 0 or greater than 50.

Answer (score 0):

When the `num` variable becomes `-1` you are accessing array elements out of bounds ( `array[-1]` ) thus invoking [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) which results in corrupted stack. The same will happen if you accept input greater than `50`. Make sure the `num` variable stays within the `0..50` boundary. Introduce another variable to control the logic and the `while` loop:

```
int controlvar = 0;
int num = 0;
int array[max] = { 0 };
std::cout << "Enter integer number from 0 to 50 and type in -1 to show occurence: ";
while (controlvar != -1)
{
    std::cin >> controlvar;
    if (controlvar >= 0 && controlvar <= 50){
        num = controlvar;
        array[num] = array[num] + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: so if I still want to use array and my endpoint is -1, is there any solution?